# nUnit Test Runner - Test stays in "Not run" if it takes over a certain amount of time

Tags: visual-studio-2012, selenium, nunit, automated-tests, visual-studio-test-runner

We have some Selenium tests built with nUnit that take quite a while to complete. We are finding that they stay in the "Not run tests" grouping even though they should pass.

After some initial investigation we found that if we remove some long running steps the tests will pass correctly but as soon as we shove a sleep in the code that waits for a couple of minutes the problem comes back.

We are using Visual Studio 2012 with the nUnit Test Runner extension as shown here: http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.2

Is there some hidden timeout in nUnit or the test runner that we need to change to get our tests (no matter how long they take) to pass or is there some other problem at work here?

Comment: Do you get the same issue running it on the command line or using the NUnit GUI?

Comment: If we use nUnit directly it passes fine. It appears to be a problem/setting with the test runner plugin itself

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the adapter. It would be cool, if you would open a bug with some reproduction code on the project's github page: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter